# Layout properties from AngularJs Material not working

Tags: angularjs-material

I am trying to use the layouts properties from AngularJs Material. For example `layout`, `layout-margin`, `flex` but for some reason it is not applying to the css.

I can use `md-raised-button`, `md-toolbar`, `md-autocomplete`, `md-form-field`. So looks like my configuration is correct.

Inside the `app.module.ts` i have:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';
```

My `package.json` has:

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.5",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

My `index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My App</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Am i missing an import? I couldn't figure it out from the documentation.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Comment: Am i looking the wrong documentation? Angular Material 2 doesn't support the properties i want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material - https://material.angular.io - uses not the same layout properties as Angular**JS** Material - https://material.angularjs.org - did. So you cannot use `layout`, `layout-margin`, `flex`, etc directly.

I guess it caused a lot of confusion in its time. I strongly advice you to rename the question and add the appropriate tags to avoid misunderstanding (as well as self-answer it, if you could). I'm sure you had already figured the difference out, but for the sake of encyclopaedic reasons (as soon as SO is a kind of encyclopaedia for developers now) it would be very cool to make this article useful for others in future.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sure, Lece, I tried to comment the question first in fact, but faced this rep blocker. Just wanted to put this info here 'cos I spent some time on it and wanted to help others to avoid the same.

Comment: Don't worry, that was sent from [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)